# How to type Ant design with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd, styled-components

This is a classic point during code reviews in my company, usually we work around typing styled components that use an Ant component with:

```
const StyledInput = styled<any>(InputAnt)`
  ${p =>
    p.hasError &&
    `
    border-color: ${p.theme.red};
  `}
`
```

far from ideal though as this behaves as any other component and needs more strict typing. Interesting enough, the obvious approach works only for some components. See

```
interface ButtonP extends NativeButtonProps {
  isCustomProp: boolean
}

export const Button = styled<ButtonP>(p => <AntButton {...p} />)`
  color: ${p => p.isCustomProp ? 'pink' : 'steelblue'};
`
```

however, other components will need different typing mechanisms. For example, the same approach with Ant's Input will not work!:

```
interface StyledInputP extends InputProps {
  hasError: boolean
}

const StyledInput = styled<StyledInputP>(p => <InputAnt {...p} />)`
  ${p =>
    p.hasError &&
    `
    border-color: ${p.theme.red};
  `}
`
```

Is there a guide or an answer somewhere that resolves this once and for all!?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can try to modify like this

```
interface StyledInputP extends InputProps {
  hasError: boolean
}

const StyledInput = styled((p: StyledInputP) => <Input {...p} />)`
  ${p =>
      p.hasError &&
        `
    border-color: ${p.theme.red};
  `}
`;
```